# #include loop C++

Tags: c++

I'm a noob in game development and i want to make a simple platform game in C++.
The problem is whenI make two classes (Game and Graphics) I can't include Game.h in Graphics.h because I have already included Graphics.h in Game.h.
Can anybody help me? 
code:
Game.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Graphics.h"

struct Game {
    Game();

    void init();
    void handle();

    bool running;

    Graphics g;
};
```

Graphics.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>

struct Graphics {
    SDL_Surface* screen;

    void init();

    void rect(SDL_Rect rect, Uint32 color);
    void rect(SDL_Rect rect, int r, int g, int b);
    void rect(int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 color);
    void rect(int x, int y, int w, int h, int r, int g, int b);

    void render(Game* game);
};
```

Comment: Keep in mind that technical questions about programming languages  is more suited for http://stackoverflow.com/ instead. This isn't exactly game related.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, an advice: keep [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com)
under your pillow. Go there at the minimum doubt you encounter with the language.

More specifically about the problem you are facing regading recursive includes, check out this article http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/, go to the section 4 of the article.

Applying the guidelines described in above mentioned article, you have to forward declare class Game in Graphics.h file, while you have to include Graphics.h in Game.h.

Game.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Graphics.h"

struct Game {
    Game();

    void init();
    void handle();

    bool running;

    Graphics g;
};
```

Graphics.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>

// Forward declaration
struct Game;

struct Graphics {
    SDL_Surface* screen;

    void init();

    void rect(SDL_Rect rect, Uint32 color);
    void rect(SDL_Rect rect, int r, int g, int b);
    void rect(int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 color);
    void rect(int x, int y, int w, int h, int r, int g, int b);

    void render(Game* game);
};
```

Comment: Note that "#pragma once" is not a part of the C or C++ standards;  it's not guaranteed to work everywhere, and can quite legally be ignored by a compiler, resulting in multiply-declared-symbol errors.  Check out [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) for the standards-compliant and guaranteed-portable way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @TrevorPowell You are technically right, however, it is actually supported by [every major compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability).

Comment: Yup.  Just pointing out that like all `#pragma` directives, it's not guaranteed to be present or to do anything in particular.  [Relevant discussion on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard).  Also, [there's a fun bug in current gcc which results in `#pragma once` incorrectly excluding header files under specific conditions](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52566).  That bug has been there for at least 18 months, and note the priority level set on getting a fix for it.